# Provide Write and Modify permission to Authenticated User

Tags: powershell, icacls

I am having this below code where I am trying to remove and then provide Modify and write access to the Authenticated User for D:\ drive

```
$systemDrives = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | where {($_.Name -eq "D")}
foreach($driveLetter in $systemDrives)
{
$path = $driveLetter.Root
icacls $path /remove "Authenticated Users"
icacls $path /grant "Authenticated Users:M,W"

}
```

the `/remove` part is removing the authenticated user from the drive but when I am doing `/grant`, it is creating the user back but not assigning the permissions.

Please let me know what I am missing here

Comment: Try : icacls $path /grant "Authenticated Users:($driveLetter,W)"

Comment: @jdweng: same issue. it is not assigning the permission

Comment: Are you running script As Admin? Right click PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: @jdweng: Yes. executing as admin itself

Comment: Verify you can write to folders.  Use File Explorer an manually create a file.

Comment: @jdweng: yes I have admin access to the server. so can write in folder. verified that

Comment: How are you verifying the permissions did not change?  See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38725364/icacls-permissions-not-applying-as-i-expect